# microsoft access 2010 vba dao recordset findfirst

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, dao, recordset

I have a table named QB that has a field name Item.  I'm trying to use find first on it with

```
Dim curDatabase As DAO.Database
  Set curDatabase = CurrentDb
  Set rsQB = curDatabase.OpenRecordset("QB", dbOpenDynaset)

  'This works and equals the value for Item in the first record of the table 
  msgbox (rsQB("Item").Value)

  'Item_No.Value is a string.  The following all do not work:
  rsQB.FindFirst "[Item] = " & Item_No.Value
  rsQB.FindFirst ("[Item] = " & Item_No.Value)
  rsQB.FindFirst "[Item] = '" & Item_No.Value &"'"



  rsQB.Close
```

Comment: What error message does this one give you? `rsQB.FindFirst "[Item] = '" & Item_No.Value & "'"`